# How to Show Subgraphs are Cycles Given the Minimum Number of Vertices which Need to be Removed for the Graph to Become Disconnected?

Tags: graph-theory

> $k(G) :=$ Minimum number of vertices which need to be removed such that the
>   graph becomes disconnected.

If $k(G) \ge n \ge 3$, show that every set of $n$ points in $G$ make a cycle.

How do I show this?

Comment: Are you saying every induced subgraph on n vertices contains a subgraph which is an n-cycle?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the claim is true if we interpret the question as "every set of $n$ points induce a subgraph that contains an $n$-cycle." A counter-example will be the complete bipartite graph $K_{4,4}$.

I believe the claim is "every set of $n$ points is contained in a cycle in $G$." That will be a restatement of Dirac's theorem generalizing the fact that every 2 vertices in a 2-connected graph lies on a common cycle. The general idea is to take a cycle containing the most number of the $n$ points. If it contains all $n$ points, we are done. Otherwise we can obtain a cycle containing with more of the $n$ points using Menger's theorem. There are a few technicalities in the procedure so I shall refer to the proof provided [here](http://books.google.com.sg/books?id=K6-FvXRlKsQC&pg=PA102&dq=%22then+every+k+vertices+of+G+lie+on+a+common+cycle+of+G.%22&hl=en&ei=WJBTTqS0Oerj4QTZ2PmzBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22then%20every%20k%20vertices%20of%20G%20lie%20on%20a%20common%20cycle%20of%20G.%22&f=false).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose $k(G)\ge n\ge 3$ and that there exists a set of $n$ vertices that do not induce an $n$-cycle. What can can you say about the $k(G)$ of such a graph? In particular, what happens in $G$ if I delete a subset of these vertices?